# Algolia not handle ORs of ANDs filter condition

Tags: filter, logic, algolia

Am using Algolia for search engine and I would like to fetch result from algolia as follows

1. If visibility = everyone, then it will show to all users
2. If visibility = private, then it will only for logged in user

To achieve that, i tried

```
filter="visibility:everyone" OR  ("visibility:me" AND "user.username:testuser")
```

But it return below error

```
{
  "message": "filters: filter (X AND Y) OR Z is not allowed, only (X OR Y) AND Z is allowed",
  "status": 400
}
```

How can i alter the condition to achieve above scenario?

Any help will appreciate and thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition can be simplified to

```
filter="visibility:everyone" OR "user.username:testuser"
```

which works with Algolia.

P.S. To make it more secure specify the filters directly to a [secured API key](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/security/api-keys/#secured-api-keys) and don't send it directly with a query.

Answer (score 3):

try changing And Gate to OR Gate by two times implementing NOT
for your case

NOT ("visibility:everyone" AND  (NOT "visibility:me" OR NOT "user.username:testuser"))